# MyBatis : Update crud operation is not updating properly

Tags: java, xml, spring-boot, mybatis

I wrote `MyBatis` `update crud operation` by using a `xml mapper`.
Here is my `xml mapper` and `parametertype`,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE mapper PUBLIC "-//mybatis.org//DTD Mapper 3.0//EN" "http://mybatis.org/dtd/mybatis-3-mapper.dtd" >
<mapper namespace="com.tera.mappers.DocumentMapper">

    <update id="updateApplicantRequestHistory" parameterType="com.tera.dao.AgentApplicantHistoryUpdateDao">
        UPDATE applicant_registration_request_history SET DOCUMENT_ID = #{documentId}, LAST_UPDATED_USER = #{lastUpdatedUser}, LAST_UPDATED_TIME = now()
        WHERE APPLICANT_REQUEST_HISTORY_ID = #{requestHistoryId}
    </update>

</mapper>
```

And parameterType,

```
package com.tera.dao;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class AgentApplicantHistoryUpdateDao implements Serializable {

    private int documentId;
    private String lastUpdatedUser;
    private int requestHistoryId;

    public AgentApplicantHistoryUpdateDao(){

    }

    public int getDocumentId() {
        return documentId;
    }

    public void setDocumentId(int documentId) {
        this.documentId = documentId;
    }

    public String getLastUpdatedUser() {
        return lastUpdatedUser;
    }

    public void setLastUpdatedUser(String lastUpdatedUser) {
        this.lastUpdatedUser = lastUpdatedUser;
    }

    public int getRequestHistoryId() {
        return requestHistoryId;
    }

    public void setRequestHistoryId(int requestHistoryId) {
        this.requestHistoryId = requestHistoryId;
    }
}
```

I called this mapper in my service class like this,

```
public void updateApplicantRequestHistory(int documentId, String lastUpdatedUser, int requestHistoryId) {
        try {
            AgentApplicantHistoryUpdateDao agentApplicantHistoryUpdateDao = new AgentApplicantHistoryUpdateDao();
            agentApplicantHistoryUpdateDao.setDocumentId(documentId);
            agentApplicantHistoryUpdateDao.setLastUpdatedUser(lastUpdatedUser);
            agentApplicantHistoryUpdateDao.setRequestHistoryId(requestHistoryId);
            this.documentMapper.updateApplicantRequestHistory(agentApplicantHistoryUpdateDao);
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

I couldn't get any update to relevant columns after calling above service method.There wasn't any exception either.

Is there any thing done incorrectly ? What is your opinion about this matter ?

Comment: There are many possibilities. Could you provide a small project reproducing the problem? Here are some [project templates](https://github.com/harawata/mybatis-issues).